# Loading a session file with vSphere PowerCLI .net API does not work

Tags: .net, authentication, vmware, powercli

I am using vSphere PowerCLI SDK to send some commands via F# and .Net to one of my virtual machines. In order to connect, I was using the `vimClient.Login(username, password)` function and everything was working fine. Unfortunately, I would like to not have to enter my username and password each time, and not leave it hard coded in the code either.

A solution I have found was to save a session file and load it next time I would like to send commands via F# and .Net, like is explained in the following VMware documentation (bottom of page 14): [VMware documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/doc/viwin_devg.pdf)

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The file gets created properly when I call `vimClient.SaveSession("VimSession.txt")`, but when I `vimClient.LoadSession("VimSession.txt")` and then try to get Entities with the following line:

```
let vmViews = vimClient.FindEntityViews(typedefof<VirtualMachine>, null, filterVms, null)
                |> Seq.cast<VirtualMachine>
                |> Seq.toList
```

I get a null error, thus meaning it did not find any views.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. I was closing the client's connection, so when I loaded my session file, it did not work as the connection was not left opened, which is logical thinking back on it now.

Make sure to not call `vimClient.Logout()` if ever you want to use session files, or else you will run into the same problem as I have. Be careful too as I think there is a timeout on the vSphere server for opened sessions that are inactive too long, so that can become a problem as well (but is configurable).